# Angular2 xlink:href Issues

Tags: javascript, svg, sprite, angular

I have got a `*ngFor` and inside that I'm writing some SVG with `<use>` tags to link to a specific part of the svg:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 8 8"><use [attr.xlink:href]="'sprite.svg#' + item.icon"></use></svg>
```

this doesn't seem to work, as it won't load the SVG into the file.

However, if i use the following it works (without ng, just to show, that it's not a wrong path):

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 8 8"><use xlink:href="sprite.svg#file"></use></svg>
```

Comment: What Angular version are you using.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5548 but should be fixed since a while.

Comment: Yep, it really looks like this has being address with this PR: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6363 I'm not sure however it made it into beta.5. From the commit log it seems so. Ivan could you try using beta.05 and see whether it resolves your issue?

Answer (score 3):

As even with ng2 beta 6 the bug seems to presist, I found, that adding an empty regular html-tag `xlink:href=""` works around the the issues and the specified id of the svg loads correctly.

Now instead of this:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 8 8"><use [attr.xlink:href]="'sprite.svg#' + item.icon"></use></svg>
```

The code has been changed to this (just added an empty `xlink:href=""`):

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 8 8"><use [attr.xlink:href]="'sprite.svg#' + item.icon" xlink:href=""></use></svg>
```

Comment: That's great! I seems Angular fails in adding the attribute but not in updating it. I think there is a similar issue open since a long time in Polymer as well.

Answer (score -3):

I am not fully understand,but if you use href ,check this ,may it help you.

```
 <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank" ></a>
```