# Angular 2 template with SVG <textPath> xlink:ref attribute not referencing associated <path> via ID

Tags: angular, svg, xlink

I have an Angular 2+ component that has SVG in it's template, and it works well.

```
template: `
<svg:path class="OutlineSegment" [attr.d]="svgPath" id="outlineSegmentPath"></svg:path>
<svg:text class="DartDistanceOnSeam">
    <svg:textPath alignment-baseline="top" xlink:href="#outlineSegmentPath">
       {{ length | number: '1.2-2' }} {{ displayUnit }}
    </svg:textPath>
</svg:text>
`
```

Alas, all the text is rendered along the same path for all instances of the component, since they seem to be referencing the same #outlineSegmentPath.

I can't seem to target the particular path created in this component.  Of course the path's ID attribute is static in the template.

Do I need to generate unique IDs myself, or is their an Angular way to knitting together IDs and xlink:href references within a component?

Comment: Not into angular, but nor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082657/angular2-svg-xlinkhref or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337695/angular2-xlinkhref-issues answer your question?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5145) discusses the issue.  It would seem a solution needs to be home baked.  Perhaps a UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by generating my own id to render in the path and textPath tags. I used UUIDs.

```
private _id: string;
get id(): string { 
    if (!this._id) {
      this._id = UUID.UUID();  // from from 'angular2-uuid'
    }
    return this._id;
}
get hashId(): string {
  return `#${this.id}`;
}
```

and in the template:

```
<svg:path [attr.d]="svgPath" [attr.id]="id"></svg:path>
<svg:text dy="-4">
    <svg:textPath [attr.xlink:href]="hashId">
        {{ length | number: '1.1-1' }} {{ displayUnit }}
    </svg:textPath>
</svg:text>
```